# Displaying Pending users within CP users field (in plugin template)

Tags: plugin-development, users, control-panel

I'm displaying a Users field within a template within a CP plugin, but when editing the entry, only Users that are active are being shown. Here is my field:

```
{{ forms.elementSelect({
    id: 'schoolteacher',
    name: 'fields[schoolTeacher]',
    elementType: craft.elements.getElementType("User"),
    elements: school.schoolTeacher | default,
    criteria: {"kind":[],"localeEnabled":null,"locale":"en_gb"},
    jsClass: 'Craft.AssetSelectInput',
    addButtonLabel: 'Select school teacher',
    sources: ['group:2']
}) }}
```

Viewing the exact same Users field within the standard CP entries section, all users are displayed irresepective of status. I think what I need to do is amend my field to allow usrs with the Pending status to be displayed. I've tried the following, but it makes no difference:

```
criteria: {"kind":[],"localeEnabled":null,"locale":"en_gb", "status": "active, pending"},
criteria: {"kind":[],"localeEnabled":null,"locale":"en_gb", "status": "Pending"},
criteria: {"kind":[],"localeEnabled":null,"locale":"en_gb", "status": null},
```

Looking through the app, I think status: null should return all of users of any status. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would guess that would work. You have xDebug installed? Seems like a great case for it.

Comment: Which one are you guessing would work?

Comment: I would guess `"status": null` would work.